# Django: Make all Error (404, 500, etc.) URLs fallback to parent URL

Tags: python, django

I want Django to display the parent URL structure in the case the current URL encounters an error. I saw a website where `example.com/user/customer/details/invalidPage/` would show the view of `example.com/user/customer/details/`.  This mainly happened for 404s. They would be redirected to one up directory/URL structure. How would I replicate this?

I believe this is a better way to handle errors in my perspective (for my situation) rather than displaying a default or custom 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this complete example

http://loongest.com/django/django-custom-404-page/

And if you are using CBV

```
# urls.py
from some.file.views import My404View
handler404 = My404View.as_view()
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You [should](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) define special handlers in your `urls.py`

```
handler404 = 'path.to.my.custom.view'
handler500 = 'path.to.my.custom.view'
```